# Proving that $y\geq 1$ is active at the optimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given parameters $k_1, k_2 > 0$, consider the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x, y}{\text{minimize}} & k_{1} y + \dfrac{x}{1-x} \left( k_2 x^y - k_{1} + k_{1} x^y \right)\\ \text{subject to} & 0 \leq x < 1, \quad y \geq 1\end{array}$$

All numerical checks show that the optimal solution is attained at the boundary at $y^{*}=1$.
I have tried proving this and failed. Intuitively, it seems clear and simple - unless you can come up with a counterexample -  I am looking for proof. Can anyone please help?

The objective is convex in $y$ in the feasible region since its second derivative is

$$\frac{(k_1+k_2) \log^2(x) x ^{y+1}}{1-x}>0$$

The first derivative with respect to $y$ is
$$k_{1}+\frac{(k_{1}+k_{2}) \log (x)x^{y+1}}{1-x}.$$

Note, that as $x\rightarrow 1$ then the first derivative value is  $-k_{2}<0$.

The first derivative with respect to $x$ is $\frac{(k_1+k_2) ((1-x) y+1) x^y-k_1}{(x-1)^2}$.

Anyone? :)

Comment: One minor simplification is to divide the entire objective function by $k_1$ and define $k=k_2/k_1$, so that there's only one free parameter.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you for that. In fact, I look at it in the ratio way as you noted. But wasn't sure, maybe it is easier for the proof somehow. I think I have tried at least 10 versions :)